How to configure `go_router` redirect callback to let users use the app without logging in but when logged, redirect if accessing the login page?
Generic Description
I am developing an app in Flutter using go_router package. The auth logic is as follows:

the user is allowed to use the app without logging in
to access some features, the user must login
when user presses the login button (in login page), the router must invoke the redirect callback and send the user back to home, without me having to manually pop and push the login page.

Issue opened in Flutter GitHub repo
You can see the detailed situation in this link:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/147067

Inside the redirect callback, you can check the current auth state and the current path, and return the home route when the auth state is 'authenticated' and the current path is 'login'.
For example:
redirect: (_, state) {
  final authState = ... // Get auth state based on your auth/state management strategy
  final currentPath = state.fullPath; // There are other options, such as `state.matchedLocation` and `state.name`
  
  if (authState == AuthState.authenticated && currentPath == '/login') {
    return '/home';
  }
}

Additionally, you have to make sure that you navigate to the login screen with the context.go method, as context.push won't change the current location, which causes the state would still be in the previous route (in this case, the home route).
Change
context.push('/login')

to
context.go('/login')


The package has an official example that implements this behavior:

books

I also made an example with a slightly different approach to simplify the logic:

DummyMart


If you see my implementation of the redirect callback that i provided on GitHub (link provided in the question), you can see I already have implemented the same logic. Yet, the issue is that when I press the login btn, the value of state.matchedLocation (also of other attributes like state.path or state.fullPath) is always /home already.
You can find all the steps to reproduce the issue on GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/147067

The problem is that you use context.push instead of context.go. context.push only pushes the widget without actually altering the current route path.

You're right! The problem was that I was using context.push instead of context.go.
Please edit your answer with the correct solution, so that I can accept the answer

Edited to include information from comment to the answer
